# Audio Play and Pause Ionic Creator app (Audio Streaming - Radio App )

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, audio, ionic-v1

I am developing a radio app using ionic creator.
audio play function works ok, but I need to pause to audio

Another question:

Double clicking to listen to two tunes at once?

### this is audio play function,

```
function ($scope, $stateParams) {

    $scope.playWebAudio = function(){
    try{
        $scope.audio = new Audio('Audio stream URL');

        $scope.audio.play();
    }
    catch(e){
        alert(e);
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

---

### play button

```
ng-click playWebAudio()
```

Comment: $scope.audio.pause();

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
not working bro,
Please send me example,
my Source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLDBRP22C-s&t=44s

Answer (score 0):

Strop Audio you have to use $cordovaMedia plugin instead of $cordovaNativeAudio

now you have to do like this:

```
     module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaMedia) {


    var src = "/src/audio.mp3";
  var media = $cordovaMedia.newMedia(src);

  var iOSPlayOptions = {
    numberOfLoops: 2,
    playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false
  }

  media.play(iOSPlayOptions); // iOS only!
  media.play(); // Android

  media.pause();

  media.stop();

  media.release();

  media.seekTo(5000); // milliseconds value

  media.setVolume(0.5);

  media.startRecord();

  media.stopRecord();

  media.getDuration();

  media.getCurrentPosition().then(...);
});
```

for more detail refer to this tlink [enter link description here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/media/)